# Electron modify file store in .asar

Tags: javascript, electron, asar

I would like, from the Electron index.html file, to modify a config file present in the.asar of my application. In my case I need to change, if necessary, my application database config in order to work.

I understood that .asar is in readOnly and I wanted to know if there is a way to modify this config file from electron without changing its position in my application?

I see the extraResources option but I did not understand how its work.

It's also important that the config file stay in myapp/config folder.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I am also having similar issue. I want a file to be editable. Were you able to find solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

What build tool do you use? If you are using electron builder, you can check out `asarUnpack` in configuration file [here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#configuration-asarUnpack) or `extraFiles` [here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extrafiles)

Comment: For asking question please leave comment behind the question.

Comment: Yes I am using electron builder, I think asarUnpack is a good idea but apparently in my case I just need to access to my all app folder. So I tried to set asar to false but the app folder is still in read only and I can't modify anything in it. Is there a way to get my app folder like in dev mode in the build ?

Comment: Did you try to put your config file in `MyApp` instead of `MyApp/resources/app` folder? You can put these line to your `package.json`:
`"extraFiles": [{
          "from": PATH_TO_CONFIG,
          "to": "."
        }]` to try it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to edit the read-only file by first changing the file permissions programmatically and then editing it.

```
fs.chmod(filename, 0666, (error) => {
        console.log('Changed file permissions');
    });

   ...
    code to modify file
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> asar is in readonly

as you mentioned asar intended to be readonly package. For runtime-changing config, you should place it outside of asar and change values accordingly.

Comment: Sadly I can't modify the structure of my application and so I can't move my config file from it. Even with the option asar: false the folder is still in read only, do you know how can I access to my application folder without restriction ?

Answer (score 0):

To manage settings you should use a node package that's specifically designed for this, like [`electron-settings`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-settings) or [`preferences`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preferences).

As an alternative one may manually read an write config files that you place in the platform's native config directory.

---

Mutable application settings shouldn't be stored in the asar file. If it's required to replace a file in an asar archive for any other reason, use the the [`asar`](https://github.com/electron/asar) program to extract the entire archive to a temporary directory, replace the file(s) you want, then create a new asar file, replacing the original asar file.

Answer (score 0):

- To unpack .asar files -> `asar extract electron.asar app`
- modify as per your needs
- To pack .asar files -> `asar pack . electron.asar`